# Implementing interface containing a get only property with T? against a concrete type with property T

Tags: c#, interface, nullable

This question is hard to describe so I apologise if it has been answered before. I am using `DateTime` and `DateTime?` types to illustrate the problem but my question is not specific to DateTime (could be any `T`/`T?`).

I have an interface for `IPotentiallyOpenDateRange` as described below. The End is a get-only nullable DateTime.

```
public interface IPotentiallyOpenDateRange
{
    DateTime Start
    {
        get;
    }

    DateTime? End
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

If I create a concrete class `OpenRange` (below), everything works as expected

```
public class OpenRange : IPotentiallyOpenDateRange
{
    public DateTime Start
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime? End
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

But the compiler will not accept the following `ClosedRange` implementation

```
public class ClosedRange : IPotentiallyOpenDateRange
{
    public DateTime Start
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Given that `DateTime` is a subset of `DateTime?` (by definition, any `T` is a subset of `T?`), and that `IPotentiallyOpenDateRange` does not have a setter, I have two questions:

1. Why is this not permitted?; and
2. Is there a way of implementing `ClosedRange` such that it satisfies `IPotentiallyOpenDateRange`?

Comment: where do you get that `definition` from? A `T?` is a syntactic sugar for `System.Nullable<T>` and so `T` does NOT derive from `T?`

Comment: That is how it is implemented, yes. What I mean by the definition is the raison d'être for T? is to have a T that you can assign null to. Here is another example that is acceptable: `public DateTime? AnotherDate => DateTime.Now;`

Comment: That's only possible because of the implicit conversion between the types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.op_implicit?view=net-5.0   You aren't assigning a `DateTime` to a `Nullable<DateTime>` ever.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is: what would you expect if someone did this `((IPotentiallyOpenDateRange) new ClosedRange()).EndDate = null;`? This is why `ClosedRange.EndDate` setter must be able to accept a null, even if it may decide to throw in the setter. You may be better off creating another interface `IClosedRange` and having `IPotentiallyOpenRange` inherit from it.

Comment: IPotentiallyOpenDateRange.End has no setter. Therefore I would expect a compiler error "Property or indexer 'IPotentiallyOpenDateRange.End' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only". (In fact you would get the same error if you ftried to assign a plain old DateTime.Now instead of null). If my interface had a setter then your concern would indeed be the deal breaker, but it doesn't apply to my presented scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types must match for a class to implement an interface. Implementing does not allow for implicit conversions.

But it is easy to get around.

Try this:

```
public class ClosedRange : IPotentiallyOpenDateRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    DateTime? IPotentiallyOpenDateRange.End
    {
        get
        {
            return this.End;
        }
    }
}
```

Or even more succinctly like this:

```
    DateTime? IPotentiallyOpenDateRange.End => this.End;
```

Comment: Perfect. I had tried that previously except my real life equivalent of `ClosedRange` is actually equivalent to an `IClosedRange` interface. Because the C# version on this project was too old, it didn't support default interface implementations but I misread it as the same error above.